# WPF C# - Live countdown visible in string

Tags: c#, wpf, time, countdown

I am writing a piece of code in C# and i have a DateAndTimeSpan created programmatically as such:

```
var date = Convert.ToDateTime("24/12/2013");
var ts = Convert.ToDateTime("10:00 PM").TimeOfDay;
var dateTime = date + ts;
var datediff = DateTime.Now - dateTime;
myCountdownLabel.Content = String.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", datediff.Days, datediff.Hours, datediff.Minutes, datediff.Seconds);
```

My question is: instead of just showing the datedifference at the time of the generation of the code and then having to press a refresh button to recalculate the string, how can I make this become a live countdown where the string assigned to the myCountdownLabel.Content ticks down each second that passes?

Also, I have about 10 different countdowns in my app so this should be applicable to more than just 1 countdown and not just for this one countdown if possible.

Regards,

Simon

Comment: You can use a timer for this task

Comment: Even for multiple countdowns? If would have a few countdowns to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [DispatcherTimer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) page at MSDN. Here is an example:

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Update myCountdownLabel here
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,10); // Set next time interval
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is that the countdowns are not all defined because even though I have 6 defined and regular countdowns, there are 4 labels that are variable and are created programatically and are childs of different containers.

Comment: I don't completely understand your comment, but see my edited answer... you can reset the time that the next interval will be each time if that helps.